# I have a shell command in hdfs and that is working in shell script.I want to convert that command so that it can be executed in python script

Tags: python

Shell script command is :
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/ | sort | awk  '{ if (index($8, ".hive") == 0 && $6 <= "'"delete_up_to_epoch_date"'" && $7 <= "'"delete_up_to_epoch_hour:00"'") print $8 }'
         + str(date_from).zfill(2) + '*'

---

Basically i want in to be executed in python script.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can open a pipe to excute your command.

```
import os

p = os.popen("YOUR_COMMAND")
```

Comment: import os

p = os.popen("hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/ | sort | awk  '{ if (index($8, ".hive") == 0 && $6 <= "'"2016-02-10"'" && $7 <= "'"05:00"'") print $8 }'")
Right ?

Comment: yes but you have to take care to escape everything decently. E.g. \" and \'

Comment: How can i get the 1st ten files.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudoish with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-hdfs/

```
import pyhdfs
from operator import itemgetter

fs = pyhdfs.connect('hostname', 12345)

path = '/user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/'

for f in sorted(fs.listdir(path), key=itemgetter('name')):
    # {kind, name, last_mod, size, replication, block_size, owner, group, permissions, last_access}
    is_hive = f['name'].endswith('.hive')
    is_old_enough = f['last_mod'] <= delete_up_to_in_right_format
    if is_hive and is_old_enough:
        print f['name']+str(date_from).zfill(2)+ '*'
```

I don't quite get the last `str(date_from).zfill(2)`  - that's not valid shell